# Click on dynamic buttons does not work (python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, button

I have to enter the passw (numeric) by clicking on some buttons, in the correct order. The problem is that each button has a pair of values (eg: "1 ou 4", "3 ou 8") and each time the user enters the page, these values change.

I've implemented a for loop matching the text of each element (button) with the password contained in a string list. The thing is that it worked the first two days, but now it clicks only in the third pair of buttons. In this case buttons "1 ou 4", and the delete button.

[image: buttons]

Note that 'clave' is a string which contains the password.

```
a = dv.find_elements_by_id('campoTeclado')
index=0
lista_acceso = []
for elem in clave:
    lista_acceso.append(elem)
    for i in a: 
        texto = i.text.replace(' ou ', '')
        time.sleep(2)
        if lista_acceso[index] in texto:
            print(lista_acceso[index]+' '+texto)
            i.click()
            time.sleep(2)
    index +=1
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="teclado clearfix">
<div class="teclas clearfix">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="campoTeclado" rel="tecla_A" class="tecla left" role="button" tabindex="0">6 ou 7</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="campoTeclado" rel="tecla_C" class="tecla left" role="button" tabindex="0">3 ou 9</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="campoTeclado" rel="tecla_K" class="tecla left" role="button" tabindex="0">1 ou 4</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="campoTeclado" rel="tecla_F" class="tecla left" role="button" tabindex="0">0 ou 5</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="campoTeclado" rel="tecla_G" class="tecla left" role="button" tabindex="0">2 ou 8</a>
         <a href="javascript:;" aria-label="apagar todo o campo de senha eletrônica" class="tecla icon left" id="btnApagar" rel="teclaLimpar" role="button" tabindex="0"><span class="icon-tecla-voltar">Apagar</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

The code above does not bring up any error, it prints out the correct texts of each element that matches each number in the password in it's correct order. And it does not bring up any error in the click() line either.

Then, I added an explicit wait. As a result, I can confirm that the elements are clickable and visible, but are not selected, as it seems from the result of the code below.

```
a = dv.find_elements_by_id('campoTeclado')
index=0
lista_acceso = []
for elem in clave:
    lista_acceso.append(elem)
    for i in a: 
        texto = i.text.replace(' ou ', '')
        time.sleep(2)
        if lista_acceso[index] in texto:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(dv, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_selected((i)))
                print(lista_acceso[index]+' '+texto)
                time.sleep(2)
                i.click()
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Nope!")
    index +=1
```

This code prints out the TimeoutException message in each loop.

How can I select and click on the correct elements?

Comment: How did  you confirm that element is visible & clickable? i think you should try - WebDriverWait(dv, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(i))

Comment: Because I used "EC.element_to_be_clickable".

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by changing the chrome window zoom to 100%. I've read lot of people's descriptions of similar issues. And one of them solved it by adjusting the zoom to 100%. So I did it, and now the code works. I hate these kind of situations...